# Algorithm that partitions a set coordinates around X number of fixed centroid coordinates?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I understand that in K-means you select how many clusters you want and the result is the location of each centroid.

How does one handle a situation when you know how many and where each centroid is, but want to partition a set of xy coordinates into corresponding clusters?

Is there an "out of the box" solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clustering anymore. Because there is no "structure" that you "discover". Furthermore, it is no longer unsupervised, but supervised.

What you are doing is simply **1NN classification**. Every object is labeled the same way as the closes *training* example.